# Getting a validation error in mongoose even though files are provided

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting a validation error with the following message on saving to database even though I have provided all the fields,

```
{ [ValidationError: Validation failed]
  message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { Name: 
      { [ValidatorError: Path `Name` is required.]
        message: 'Path `Name` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'Name',
        type: 'required',
        value: undefined } } }
```

This is how the object that I am trying to save looks like

```
    { Name: 'Nobody Singh',
  phone: '+919177121364',
  address: 'flat no 306 koratala apartments\nstreet no 3 ,Himayatnagar, Near Siraj plaza',
  start: '2014-12-03T13:00:00.000Z',
  end: '2014-12-03T15:00:00.000Z',
  details: 'flat no 306 koratala apartments\nstreet no 3 ,Himayatnagar, Near Siraj plaza' }
```

an here are the schema

```
    // load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for our user model
var appointmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       email: { type: String, default: 'maisnamraj@gmail.com' },          
       name: { type: String, required:true },
       phone: { type:Number },
       address:{ type: String },
       details:{ type: String },
       title:{ type: String, default: "Slot Taken"},
       start: { type:Date},
       end: { type:Date},
       requestedDate: { type:Date, default: Date.now }

});



// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Appointment', appointmentSchema);
```

Here is the route file

```
app.post('/saveappointment', function(req, res) {

var appointment = new Appointment();

    var appointMent = {
                      //need to add an email here 
                      name: req.body.name,
                      phone: req.body.phone,
                      address: req.body.address,
                      start: req.body.appointment.start,
                      end:req.body.appointment.end,
                      details:req.body.details,
                      address:req.body.address
                    };

    console.log(appointMent);

    appointment.save(appointMent,
     function(err,resp) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send({
                message :'something went wrong'
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                message:'the appointment has bees saved'
            });
        }           

    });
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code below and let me know if the same error will appear

```
app.post('/saveappointment', function(req, res) {

  var appointment = new Appointment({
    //need to add an email here 
    name: req.body.name,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    address: req.body.address,
    start: req.body.appointment.start,
    end: req.body.appointment.end,
    details: req.body.details,
    address: req.body.address
  });


  appointment.save(function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send({
        message: 'something went wrong'
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        message: 'the appointment has been saved'
      });
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: That worked like a charm :D can you explain what it was I did wrong ?

Comment: your error was that you inserted object into mongoose save ,correct way is to call save function on mongoose.model object and provide only callback as it's parameter not additional object
see documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to install ( **npm install body-parser --save**), and use it in your express server as below (app.js). hope this answer help someone :)

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/api',api)
module.exports = app
```